# REST API - using PUT method for removing attributes

Tags: rest, put

We are restrained on using only PUT method for updating a resource, so PATCH is not an option (unfortunately).

Context: there are cases of fields mapped on attributes which are defined as Optional and Editable, meaning the user may remove the previous inputted and previously saved value.

My question:  which is the best option to save this change via the PUT method? (removing the attribute from the resource)

AFAIK there are 3 options available:

- a) send the attribute with an empty value, eg. `"invoiceSerial": ""`
- b) send the attribute with a clear null, eg. `"invoiceSerial": null`
- c) don`t send the attribute at all, and on the server side it should process all missing editable&optional attributes by removing them from the stored object

i can`t find any best practice out there, so any hint to some standard documentation is appreciated.

Comment: The issue here is if `null` is a valid value or not.

Answer (score 1):

Option ***b*** looks better compared to the others:

> a) send the attribute with an empty value, eg. `"invoiceSerial": ""`

What if `invoiceSerial` was a number? What would you send then? `0`? What if `0` is a valid value for the given property?

> b) send the attribute with a clear null, eg. `"invoiceSerial": null`

`null` is just fine to represent, well, `null` values.

> c) don`t send the attribute at all, and on the server side it should process all missing editable&optional attributes by removing them from the stored object

This approach looks more complicated to implement compared to option *b*.

Answer (score 1):

> i can`t find any best practice out there, so any hint to some standard documentation is appreciated.

I suggest that you start with [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-put)

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

If you take this idea, and work backwards, you might get a reasonable answer.  What does the representation of the resource look like after the attribute has been removed?

That probably means choice (c).

> don`t send the attribute at all, and on the server side it should process all missing editable&optional attributes by removing them from the stored object

The justification here is that PUT has the semantics of [web publishing](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put).  "Make this document available using this URI."  So your goal is to mimic the interface of a web site that supports web authoring, isolating the api consumers from the details of your implementation.

You might also want to review the links aggregated by Karl Dubost: [Understanding HTTP PUT](https://www.w3.org/blog/2008/10/understanding-http-put/).